# Lost my Windows 7 partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, windows-7

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windowws 7. I had like 3 partitions (Windows 7, DATA files and Ubuntu 14.04) I'm so sad because I had hundreds of important files in my Data partition.
Yesterday, I was able to reach my files in the launching column, but after I've done a recovery process, I encounterd the aforementioned problem. 
Note that I'm still a beginner in Linux world

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your issue. Is your Windows 7 partition deleted or are you unable to boot it? And what happened to your DATA partition?

Comment: This is written more as a comment than a question - I *think* you are asking if there is a way to recover lost data?

Comment: please elaborate on what the "recovery process" was that you did and what exactly you are trying to do, as well as if the windows partition is gone/written over in gparted or just unbootable

Answer (score 0):

if the partition disappeared entirely, then you might try gparted with gpart and try to recover partition table, though if you did not have too many mods in windows, you might just try recreating a partition approx. where it was and reinstalling then using data recovery software in windows.